# Unable to disable File Menu with C# - Word 2016

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm currently trying to disable several commands within the File Menu of Microsoft Word 2016.

Currently I have:

Main.cs:

```
protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon();
}
```

Ribbon.cs:

```
public string ReturnUI()
{
    return GetSource("Ribbon.xml");
}


private static string GetSource(string sourceName)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string[] sourceNames = asm.GetManifestSourceNames();
    for (int x = 0; x < sourceNames.Length; ++x)
    {
        if (string.Compare(sourceName, sourceNames[x], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestSourceStream(sourceNames[x])))
            {
                if (sr != null)
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Ribbon.xml:

```
<commands>
    <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
</commands>
<backstage>
    <tab idMso ="TabNew" visible="false"/>
</backstage>
```

I believe I have all the current references but perhaps not:

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (Version 15.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.Office.Tools (version 10.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word (version 10.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.Office.Common (version 10.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v4.0.Utilities (version 10.0.0.0)

This doesn't disable the "Save As" under File Menu or any other option I choose. What am I missing? Something not wired up correctly? Something out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The problem is the Backstage as it has been designed for Word 2013 and later. It's not possible to directly repurpose the Backstage commands. The code you show will work for any Ribbon buttons or keyboard shortcuts that call FileSaveAs, but not for the Backstage.

For the Backstage you have two basic approaches available to you:

1. Hide the built-in Backstage menu and build your own in the RibbonXML.
2. If available, work with an event. In this case the `DocumentBeforeSave` event could help.

If you're interested in the first option I recommend these two MSDN articles that describe in some depth how to work with the Backstage in Ribbon XML:
[Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx), 
[Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can download a list of Control IDs for Office 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798

As it is very difficult to reconstruct the entire content of the Save As tab, many people decide to work with the `DocumentBeforeSave` event.

Comment: Agreed with the File Options to File Menu, I've edited that for clarity. It sounds like the first option would be the a good fit. All I want to do is either disable it or hide, just don't let user click it or use it in any capacity.

Comment: Yes, that should not be a problem with the Backstage scenario - much simpler than using an event! But don't forget you'll need what you already have for the other things that call FileSaveAs :-)

Comment: Aww, so I did check and I do have <backstage>
    <tab idMso ="TabNew" visible="false"/></backstage> but the "New" is still visible. Any ideas? Do I have the correct attribute? I've edited the question body

Comment: @user94614 You shouldn't change the Question body if it nullifies/changes what people have already answered. `TabNew` certainly won't affect Save, that's `File/New`. More likely `TabSave`. Note that I'm consulting the Control ID list for Office 2013 which you can download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798

Comment: That's just the blog post I needed! I guess I need to work on my googling skills. Thank you for your help

Comment: It helps to know what you're looking for, of course. That's why we have places like this: *someone* knows! Glad I could help :-)